# CSS transition not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

I am using CSS transition to ease transition between images in a bootstrap carousel. This was working perfectly for months in Chrome and Safari. All the sudden it does not work in Chrome.

HTML (in Jade):

```
div(class="item")
    img.landing-bg(src="images/aa/ny58.jpg", alt="")
```

CSS:

```
.item {
    -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in-out 1s !important;
       -moz-transition: opacity ease-in-out 1s !important;
        -ms-transition: opacity ease-in-out 1s !important;
         -o-transition: opacity ease-in-out 1s !important;
            transition: opacity ease-in-out 1s !important;
}

.carousel .active.left {left:0;opacity:0;z-index:2;}

.carousel .active.right {right:0;opacity:0;z-index:2;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used a small plugin in one project, `.carousel-fade`, its basically what you need:

### **HTML**

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel carousel-fade slide">
  ...
</div>
```

### **CSS**

```css
/*
 * Carousel Fade Plugin
 */
.carousel-fade .item {
  -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in-out 2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity ease-in-out 2s;
  -o-transition: opacity ease-in-out 2s;
  transition: opacity ease-in-out 2s;
}

.carousel-fade .active.left,
.carousel-fade .active.right {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

[**jsFiddle example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/thiagobraga/zLA2r/)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I had to add "!important" for it to work on Chrome.

Comment: I've tried in Chrome too and didn't need to add `!important`, like in the jsFiddle. Have you  modified original bootstrap file?

Comment: No I have not modified bootstrap. Not sure why I need !important. I can see that in jsFiddle, yours works without. Will add comment with the reason if I figure it out.

Comment: Are you using the `.item` class that you wrote in your question? If yes, I think you don't need it.